# Kafka default broker logging

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

By default, kafka log4j properties come with `DailyRollingFileAppender`. Is there any reason to have this as the default logging mechanism? Schema registry uses `RollingFileAppender`.

I am trying to understand, how Kafka was degined to clean up logs by default when using DailyRollingFileAppender. Adding `log4j.appender.[appenderName].MaxBackupIndex = number of files you want to save`
 would need some jars to be added into the lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any reason to have this as the default logging mechanism?

It also [uses ConsoleAppender for the main process](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties). The daily files are mostly made to separate out the other processes by a broker.

The point of having log4j is so it can be modified via configuration. The defaults aren't going to perfect for every use case

> how Kafka was degined to clean up logs by default when using DailyRollingFileAppender

Maybe you're misunderstanding the difference between the application logs and the data logs... The server logs are not cleaned up with the default settings and requires some cron or system administrator to go do it, by default

> MaxBackupIndex would need some jars to be added

Not that I know of? Log4j should include all the necessary libraries to offer its features.